# Field extension over the reals

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am studying these days filed theory and i'm new to this subject,so my question may be to trivial.
The field extension $\mathbb{R}$(${\sqrt{5}}$)/$\mathbb{R}$ has degree $1$ or $2$?
We see that $\mathbb{R}$=$\mathbb{R}$(${\sqrt{5}}$) so a basis ot this field extension extention must be the set {1} or is the set {$1$,${\sqrt{5}}$} ?

Comment: Aren't you rather thinking about $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Since $\;\sqrt r\in\Bbb R\;$ for any $\;0<r\in\Bbb R\;$ , you trivially get $\;\Bbb R(\sqrt r)=\Bbb R\;$ , so you must probably want $\;\Bbb Q\;$ instead, just as Vincent wrote.

Comment: the basis of this field extension is the set {1}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have observed, $\mathbb{R}(\sqrt{5})$ is just $\mathbb{R}$, since $\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{R}$.  For any field $K$, considered as a vector space over itself, $\{1\}$ is a basis, since every element $a\in K$ is in its span (namely as the scalar product $a\cdot 1$).  Note that $\{1,\sqrt{5}\}$ is not linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$, since $\sqrt{5}\cdot 1+(-1)\cdot \sqrt{5}=0$ (here the first parts of each term are coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$).